# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string Eventbrite API

Tags: php, object, stdclass, eventbrite

I'm trying to upgrade a site from the old Eventbrite API to the new one. This php code had worked fine on the old one.

I'm trying to save events from Eventbrite in to an events section on our own site.

I get the event from eventbrite no problem:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/'.$id.'?token=evbsecrettoken');
$event = json_decode($json);
```

Then I try to save it to our site, using a save function that I know works from our backend

```
$eventId = $this->config->DS->saveEvent('new',
                    $event->name->text,
                    $event->description,
                    $countryId,
                    $cityId,
                    $venueId,
                    $event->start->local,
                    '',
                    0,
                    0,
                    $image,
                    $_SESSION['admin']['user_id']);
```

The saveEvent function looks like

```
public function saveEvent($id, $title, $body, $country, $city, $venue, $date, $cost, $ticker, $active, $image, $userId) {
    if($id == 'new'){
        $slug = $this->getAvailableSlugByTable('event', $title);

        $eventId = $this->addEvent($userId, $country, $city, $venue, $title, $date, $cost, $body, $image, $slug, $ticker, $active);

        return $eventId;
```

AddEvent looks like

```
 public function addEvent($userId, $country, $city, $venue, $title, $date, $cost, $text, $image, $slug, $ticker = 0, $active = 0){
    $this->dbHandler->DbQuery('INSERT event SET user_id = ?, country_id = ?, city_id = ?, venue_id = ?, event_title = ?, event_date = ?, event_cost = ?, event_text = ?, event_image = ?, event_slug = ?, event_ticker = ?, event_active = ?', Array($userId, $country, $city, $venue, $title, $date, $cost, $text, $image, $slug, $ticker, $active));

    $eventId = $this->dbHandler->lastInsertId();

    // add ticker if needed
    if($ticker){
        $this->addTicker('event', $title, $slug, $text, $image, 'events', $eventId, $userId, 0);
    }

    return $eventId;
}
```

But I get an "Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" error and the stack trace looks like:

```
[03-Feb-2016 21:11:13 UTC] PHP   7. Admin_Data_Source->saveEvent() /home/ubuntu/workspace/admin/modules/eventbrite.php:94
[03-Feb-2016 21:11:13 UTC] PHP   8. Site_Data_Source->addEvent() /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/persistence/adminDataSource.php:368
[03-Feb-2016 21:11:13 UTC] PHP   9. DBhandler->DbQuery() /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/persistence/siteDataSource.php:553
[03-Feb-2016 21:11:13 UTC] PHP  10. PDOStatement->execute() /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/dbHandler/dbHandler.php:88
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I don't know which class is getting converted. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though one of your variables isn't a string.

Inside the addEvent function i would do a `var_dump` on each function parameter and check it's type. It's possible the image is an object instead of a string as you are expecting.